# sql query not working

Tags: php, sql

My code:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT value1 FROM My table au1 WHERE au1.value2 IN (SELECT au2.value3 FROM My table au2)");
```

My table:

Id --- value1 ---  value2 ----  value3

1 ---   Test    ---  6786    ----  5678

2 ---   Test2  ---   5678   ----  6786

With my code, the result is: Test and Test2

i would like to select value 1 where value 3 Is equal to value 2. And not in the other way.

So for this example i need only Test2 and not Test.

Answer (score 1):

```
i would like to select value 1 where value 3 Is equal to value 2
```

You can use the below query for that. You don't have to use `au`. Just don't use alias for the sake of using it. Use when you have to use.

Preferred query

```
SELECT value1 FROM `My table` WHERE value2 = value3;
```

According to your query

```
SELECT au1.value1 FROM `My table` au1 WHERE au1.value2 = au1.value3;
```

## For your information

`My table` is not a accpetable way of naming a table. It should be `my_table`

Comment: if i try this i get no value1. everything is null

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select value1 where value2 equals value3, use this query:

```
SELECT value1 FROM My table au1 WHERE au1.value2 = au1.value3
```

Comment: if i try this i get no value1. everything is null

Comment: That is because there is no row in your table where value2 is equal to value3.

Answer (score 1):

`My table` is not a valid table name, escape it like :

```
SELECT value1 FROM `My table` au1 
WHERE au1.value2 IN (SELECT au2.value3 FROM `My table` au2);
```

Or, you can `JOIN` the tables instead:

```
SELECT value1 
FROM `My table` au1 
INNER JOIN `My table` au2 ON au1.value2 = au2.value3;
```

Comment: when i try 
    SELECT value1 
FROM `My table` au1 
INNER JOIN `My table` au2 ON au1.value2 = au2.value3;

i get error: Column 'device_token' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you want `test2` because it has a value3 which exists as value2 somewhere in the table. Currently you get `test` because it has a value2 which exists as value3 somewhere in the table. Simply swap value2 and value3 in your example query:

```
SELECT value1 FROM My table au1 WHERE au1.value3 IN (SELECT au2.value2 FROM My table au2)
```

Comment: no, i get test2 and test with my example. if i change value2 from line 1 then i get only test2 this is good. But if there numbers in the 2 directions i get test2 and test. and i only need test2. he only may look in one direction.